# HTML to Excel: How can tell Excel to treat columns as numbers?

Tags: html, excel, formatting, numbers, formulas

I need to achieve the following when opening an HTML in Excel `(Response.contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel")` :

- force Excel to consider content of td cells as numbers
- make the above so that any subsequent user-entered formulas work on these cells (when the spreadsheet is opened)

So far I was successful with adding `style="vnd.ms-excel.numberformat:0.00"` to the td cells in question. The contents of the cells are correctly shown as numbers when I right click on them in the Excel, however the formulas don't work.

If successful, that technique would be quite useful because any web Excel report could be user enhanced with appropriate formulas according to custom requirements. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 29):

If you add a CSS Class to your page:

```
.num {
  mso-number-format:General;
}
.date {
  mso-number-format:"Short Date";
}
```

And slap those classes on your TD's, does it work?

```
<td class="num">34</td>
<td class="num">17.0</td>
<td class="date">12/17/2008</td> <!-- if you are playing with dates too -->
```

***Update:*** [Additional formatting options](http://cosicimiento.blogspot.com/2008/11/styling-excel-cells-with-mso-number.html) from @Aaron.

Comment: more formatting options: http://www.netdominus.co.uk/knowledgebase/mod/resource/view.php?id=182
\@ for text came in handy

Comment: Link is dead. Try http://cosicimiento.blogspot.com/2008/11/styling-excel-cells-with-mso-number.html instead

Answer (score 16):

Here is a list of Excel formats: [Styling Excel cells with mso-number-format](http://cosicimiento.blogspot.com/2008/11/styling-excel-cells-with-mso-number.html)

Answer (score 5):

The best trick is to mock up an Excel spreadsheet with all the colors/(conditional) formats/formulas you require.

Keep it as simple as possible, just the bare minimum rows etc.

Then save the Excel spreadsheet "As Xml Spreadsheet"

Then you have a template to build a spreadsheet via Xml.

I generally clean up styles in the original Xml saved from the Excel workbook.  Removing duplicates and renaming them.

Then it is just a matter of populating with whatever datasource you have.

I do not know what environment you are coding to, but in VB.NET with LINQ and Xml Literals, this is a very simple task.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't works sometimes if you add it using a `css class` in that case try it using in `Style` to your `TD`. I did it for formatting a column to a text. like this

```
 style="mso-number-format:\@;"
```

For you it would be as

```
  mso-number-format:General
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get any of the answers on this page to work in Excel 2010. I ended up using this.

```html
<td x:num>123</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: You also need to remove non-breaking spaces (nbsp's) from td cells containing numeric or money information to make formulas work on these cells in Excel. So the problem is solved.

Comment: which answer was the solution for you? (beyond removing the non-breaking spaces) or was that the only issue?

Answer (score -1):

```
mso-number-format:0         NO Decimals
mso-number-format:"\#\,\#\#0\.000" 3 Decimals 
mso-number-format:"mm\/dd\/yy" Thousand comma with 3 decimals  
mso-number-format:"mmmm\\ d\\\,\\ yyyy" Date7 
mso-number-format:"m\/d\/yy\\ h\:mm\\ AM\/PM" Date9
```

Text Column

```
"<td style=\"mso-number-format:'\@'\">"
```

or

```
<td style="mso-number-format:'\@'">
```