# Copy HTML elements to clipboard using javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, copy, clipboard

I am **not** trying to copy text to the clipboard. I have an array of html elements (contiguous divs) representing cells in a grid. They are selected using jquery and I am trying to find out if there is a way to copy them onto the clipboard like a table that can be pasted elsewhere, like in MS excel for example.

Every resource on the internet only talks about copying text, not html elements.

Comment: You mean *contiguous ?

Comment: yep - thanks for correction

Comment: When you copy something, its usually text. The difference is that you can 'encode' the text and then paste it on a program that 'decodes' that text to in a certain way. In excel, if you paste a text with tabs and new lines, the tabs will go to next column and new line will go to next row

Comment: @juvian thanks - that makes sense and sounds like the easiest solution for now. Formatting isn't that important I suppose.

Comment: @armensg90 that is the easiest way, but if you really need to keep formatting you should look into xml: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177365/importing-html-table-into-excel-via-clipboard

Comment: I've managed to build a html table element from the divs- now i just need to figure out how to put the variable on the clipboard!

Answer (score 0):

<s>You can stringify a DOM element node or a tree using `[selector].outerHTML`. The most direct approach would be to show a prompt that contains the HTML element text, which you can then copy off of:</s>

```
var selectedText = [selector].outerHTML;
function copyToClipboard(text) {
    window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", selectedText);
}
// Using http://stackoverflow.com/a/6055620/3157745
```

---

As for the export into Excel, there's no way you can simply copy and paste a string of any sorts and drop that into a table. However, what you can do is parse the HTML element, format that into a CSV, which then can be opened with Excel. As for how that might be achieved, we'd need to see the structure of your HTML.

---

**Update**

If possible, try using [**jquery DataTables**](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html). It can export your Table as XLSX, CSV, PDF and all you would need to do is initialize your table with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable()
});
```

Comment: yeah i dont mind processing it into a csv string or something. Ill post the strucutre of my HTML