# Format html table cell numeric value as text for Excel

Tags: html, excel, date

Scenario: I am trying to export a html table to Excel file in a Web Application (website hosted online) for clients to download to their computers.

All data exported as expected, except 1 problem.

The HTML table web page is saved with file extension of XLS.

Below is the sample html page that saved as XLS file:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr><td>1/42</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

After openning this file in Excel (2019 version), the value of

```
1/42
```

is changed to

```
01/01/1942
```

and appears as

```
Jan-42
```

in Excel cell.

I have tried to prefix the value with single quote `'`.

but then the value displays as

```
'1/42
```

in Excel cell.

How to make it appears as

```
1/42
```

correctly without the single quote and avoiding the Excel auto-reformatting it into Date, and without the need of changing the Excel cell Value format.

Is there anything that I can do during writing the HTML documents?

[image: Excel auto date formatting]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer Taken from: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4620023/520848
[HTML to Excel: How can tell Excel to treat columns as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354476/html-to-excel-how-can-tell-excel-to-treat-columns-as-numbers/354574#354574)

> Formatting can be applied to the cells for numbers, text, dates, etc.

by adding CSS class:

```
.num {
  mso-number-format:General;
}
.text{
  mso-number-format:"\@";/*force text*/
}
```

add the class to the cell

```
<td class="num">34</td>
<td class="num">17.0</td>
<td class="text">067</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would open the data in notepad first.  Then open excel, change column A to a TEXT format.  Copy the data from notepad, then paste into excel using PasteSpecial>Values.  This should get you what you need.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution. But however, due to the scenario where the file has to be pre-written for client to download, it is not ok for requesting the client to manually perform the task in notepad. I have further edited my question to include this scenario.

Comment: As far as I know excel will always auto-format numbers.  You can import the file from text and/or using your '1/42 symbol use vba code upon open to do a find/replace while retaining the format.  I can write the vba code for you if you like.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tips. I have found another simpler solution, simply by adding CSS class and this will tell Excel to force to format the cell accordingly. I have post it as another answer. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When you import the html, click Transform Data and in the power query editor select the column and change the type to text, and then close&load